# Can't uninstall Java under El Capitan

Tags: java, macos

Since installing El Capitan, I am not able to run Adobe Photoshop or Dreamweaver (old versions).

I get the message "You need to install the legacy Java SE runtime"

I am trying to uninstall Java and reinstall the Java SE 6 runtime I downloaded from Apple, but even though I am sure all traces of Java are gone, I am still not able to install. Every time I try to install the runtime, I get a message that says: "Java for OS X 2014-001 can't be installed on this disk. A newer version of this package is already installed."

I already removed /Library/Java and everything under it. I also checked /etc/paths and Java is removed.

Not sure whatever vestiges of Java remain, but I am still getting the message.

Comment: You don't need to remove the Java you have just add the legacy  old Java https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US which implies that the issue you have is you do not have the latest Java 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link solved the problem for me:
[Java for OS X 2014-001: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start features](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202643)

Learn how to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start features in OS X Lion and later.

If, after installing Java for OS X 2014-001 and the latest version of Java 7 from Oracle, you want to disable Java 7 and re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start functionality, follow these steps.

Note: You must be logged in as an administrator. If prompted for your administrator password after a command, enter it and then press the Return or Enter key.

1. Open Terminal, located in the Utilities folder.
2. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled
   ```
3. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   ```
   sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled
   ```
4. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
   ```
5. To re-enable Java SE 6 Web Start, enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
   ```

Learn more

The following steps will undo the above commands and restore Java 7 in OS X Lion and later.

1. Disable Java SE 6 Web Start opening:

   - Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

     ```
     sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
     ```
   - When prompted, enter your administrator password, then press the Return or Enter key.
2. Re-enable the Java 7 applet plug-in by downloading and reinstalling the latest version of Oracle Java 7 JRE.

Comment: After I enter this, I get the following:
Operation not permitted

Comment: @user182725 I also get the "operation not permitted" error, this can be related to rootless mode, check out this page for a likely solution: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19117